# copy one column into another column in a table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table

```
ID | COUNTRY | ORIGIN
1  | INDIA    |
2  | SPAIN    |
3  |  UK     |
```

I have copy data from column Country to column ORIGIN.
How should i do this.
Please help.

Answer (score 12):

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET ORIGIN=COUNTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_table SET origin = country WHERE ...
```